# Why won't Netbeans import my sample project?

Tags: netbeans, import

I am following this [basic tutorial on creating a web application from the Netbeans website:](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-intro.html#requiredSoftware)
Yet I cannot seem to import the zip file into Netbeans. Here is what I am doing:

1. Download jsfDemo.zip
2. Open Netbeans
3. File -> Import Project -> From ZIP...
4. Select location of jsfDemo.zip
5. Select destination of project
6. Select **import**

It then displays "No Netbeans projects added". However, it did extract the contents into the destination folder.
I also made a [video showing my steps](https://youtu.be/Bdp_xoAAQsA). I didn't think this would be this difficult. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution: it would seem that the the import by zip feature is buggy with netbeans 8.0.2 When I downgraded to 8.0, the project imported fine.